# How to wire up Android Share Intent in .net MAUI?

Tags: android, maui

I'm trying to respond to Android Share Intents. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. I've started a new MAUI app in Visual Studio (latest version of MAUI, latest preview of VS as of August 15 2022).

In the AndroidManifest.xml file, I have defined the activity:

```xml
 <activity 
             android:exported="true"
             android:name="myamazijng.shareactivity" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                 <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
```

Then my activity is defined as follows:

```cs
 [Activity(Name = "myamazing.shareactivity", Exported = true)]
 public class ShareActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
 {
    
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
     {
         base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState); //throws Exception
    
         if (Intent.Type == "text/plain")
         {
                
         }
     }
```

A share intent is succesfully registered on the Android emulator. But clicking on it throws a NullReferenceEception in the call to base.OnCreate..

Digging into the Exception, it's thrown here in Microsoft.Maui.Controls at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.Compatibility.ShellToolbarTracker.OnToolbarPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) . ShellToolbarTracker.cs:line 58

Have I run into a bug? Or am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: `A share intent is succesfully registered on the Android emulator. ` Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you elaborate this in detail?

Comment: It seems like there is a bug with the latest version of MAUI (6.0.4). See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/967073/how-to-wire-up-android-share-intent-in-maui.html?childToView=975701#comment-975701) for more info.